# Selecting particular whatsapp chat and retrieve shared links

Tags: android, whatsapp

I'm a developing an app which needs to retrieve the links that are shared in particular whatsapp group chat. I have tried successfully opening whatsapp from my app, but I need to proceed further. Any ideas to share?

Thanks

Comment: I would think whatsapp does not have an official API, after googling the following link prooves I'm right: https://www.quora.com/WhatsApp-Why-doesnt-WhatsApp-have-an-API
There does exist a 3rd party PHP library but doubt that will suit your needs

Comment: You won't be able to do directly from an app. However, you may achieve this by creating a chat bot. See [this github repo](https://github.com/mgp25/Chat-API/wiki).

Comment: Okay thanks, Is there any way to save all links from a particular WhatsApp group to my Android App? Like, I will long press the message(links) and a pop up menu should appear which should have the option to store it in my app.